# regex replace JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Hi this seems very simple, but id don't understand why the first function isn't working.  I have tried a couple of variations and there is something wrong with my logic.  When I look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace it seems like I have done it properly yet it will not replace the text.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="p1">Mr Red has a red house and a red car.</p>
        <p id="p2">Mr Red has a red house and a red car.</p>

        <button onclick="replace1()">Replace red with blue</button>
        <button onclick="replace2()">Replace red with blue too</button>
        <script>
            function replace1()
            {
                var str = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;
                str.replace(/red/, "blue");
                document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = str;
            }
                function replace2()
            {
                var str = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;
                var rep = str.replace(/red/, "blue");
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = rep;
            }
    
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strings are immutable in JavaScript.

Comment: Take a look at the syntax for `str.replace` in the documentation `const newStr = str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)`... it returns the a new string, it doesn't replace the existing one. that's why button 2 works and button 1 doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. That is why the consol.log example worked but doesn't translate to the code I was trying to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first function, just need to assign the value to the variable str. update this in your code.
`str = str.replace(/red/, "blue");`